# Is there some way of editing a Facebook Messenger message?

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

Is there some way of editing a Facebook Messenger message (let's assume I misspelled a word)? I found no menu for that.

Comment: Yes, a question (current content) like this could be "answered", but that should be done using post comments, a chatroom, or another Q&A site (i.e., Reddit) if you are unwilling to use the options that offer the Stack Exchange platform. You can still improve this post to make it a good fit for this site. Through the Stack Exchange Q&A process, were are looking to build a knowledge base closer to Wikipedia than a help desk log.

Comment: It seems to have been added by now, there is edit, remove and forward!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the only way to do this is to unsend the message (as long as they haven't read it already) and send a new message.